# Can't get Selenium to find element

Tags: c#, selenium, element

I am trying to find an element on yelp.com. I have tried using `xPath` and `ClassNames` but cannot seem to be able to get it to retrieve the star ratings for each business.

Here is the star rating HTML:

```
<div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-4-half rating-large" title="4.5 star rating">
    <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/41341496d9db/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="4.5 star rating">
</div>
```

Here is my code to retrieve the rating:

```
var starRating = driverGC.FindElement(By.LinkText("title"));
MessageBox.Show(starRating.Text);
```

I would like it to return the `4.5` so I can save that to another file. I am using C# and Visual Studio.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code, both the HTML element you want to find and the code that you have written to find the element. It's quite difficult to get any help, without helping the readers of your post to understand as much as it is feasible your problem.

Comment: So far, i have this as the code to try finding it var starRating = driverGC.FindElement(By.LinkText("title")); but i have tried using XPath, ClassName, and ID but I cannot seem to get any of them to find the right element. Is there a way I can set it to search the element for a certain string so that I can be more specific?

Comment: Here is the entire code, i want to find all businesses with 3 stars or less, and write those to an external file. http://pastebin.com/ChT5eqYj

Comment: What text does this line in your code return? `starRating.Text`

Comment: Do you actually work for Yelp? Or are you creating a spam list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one result, I think you can do this. Or customize it as needed if you need to find a specific rating:

```
// The rating element
var starRating = driverGC.FindElement(By.ClassName("i-stars"));
// The title attribute on the rating element is something like '4.5 star rating'
// which I think is what you're trying to find.
MessageBox.Show(starRating.GetAttribute("title").Split(' ').First());
```

Alternatively if you want to loop through all of the elements:

```
// The rating element
IList<IWebElement> starRatings = driverGC.FindElements(By.ClassName("i-stars"));
// The title attribute on the rating element is something like '4.5 star rating'
// which I think is what you're trying to find.
foreach (IWebElement elem in starRatings)
{
    MessageBox.Show(elem.GetAttribute("title")Split(' ').First());  
}
```

The `Split(' ').First()` should return the first word, which is 4.5. Note: you'll need a `using System.Linq;` statement in order to use `First()`, or if you end up using `ToList()`.

Comment: I added this as it seemed like the best, but now i am getting error about converting the read-only collection to a list. Any fixes?

Comment: Oops, that should be `IList<IWebElement>` instead of `List<IWebElement>`. I'll update my answer. You could alternatively do `List<IWebElement> starRatings = driver.GC.FindElements(By.ClassName("I-stars")).ToList();` as well, but programming against interfaces is usually a better idea.

Comment: I also added some code to get the first word, which should be `4.5` in your example. I haven't tested this stuff so let me know if you run into another error :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find and filter businesses like this (in Java):

```
List<WebElement> starRatings = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@title, 'star rating')]"));
List<WebElement> businesses = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@title, 'star rating')]/preceding::a[1]/span"));
for(int i = 0; i < starRatings.size(); i++)
{
       String rating = starRatings.get(i).getAttribute("title");
       rating = rating.split(" ")[0];
       DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
       Double d = Double.valueOf(rating);
       rating = df.format(d);
       d = Double.valueOf(rating);
       if(d <= 3)
       {
            String Businessname = businesses.get(i).getText();
            //Write variable Businessname & rating into file 
       }
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do it with C#? I get at least 8 hours with this when i add it.